# print file that contains strings and integers, C program

Tags: c, file, scanf

First, sorry for my bad English.

So I have file contain multiple strings and integers.

the file content is

```
jonny#st.maria#100#200
antony#blabla#90#300
maria#chitchat#45#100
```

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char name[10][20], school[10][20];

int op=0, score[8], dis[8];

int read(){
  FILE *op = fopen("test.txt","r");

  while(fscanf(op,"%[^#] # %[^#] # %d # %d",name[lis],school[lis],score[lis],dis[lis]) != EOF) 
    lis++;
  fclose(op);
}
```

It will get a crash?, can you please tell the right way?

Comment: The easiest way to find why a program crashes is to compile it with symbol information (`-g` for gcc, for example) run it in a debugger. But here are some pointers to things that might lead to a crash: Where is `lis` defined? Is it initialised to zero? Why do you have 10 names and scools but only 8 scores? Why don't you check that `lis` exceeds 8 (or 10 or whetwever your upper limit is)? Why don't you limit the strings you read to 19 + 1 null chars with `%19[^#]`? Also your `fscanf` call can return anything from `EOF` to a number from 0 to 4.

Comment: what is `lis`. where do you declare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are difference sizes (some are 8, some are 10 elements long).  You should check that you do not overflow the shortest of your arrays.  Your code as shown does not compile because the variable `lis` is not defined — if it were defined, you'd need to be sure it was initialized to 0.

Your code also is misleading because you have a global variable `int op = 0;` and then inside your `read()` function you have `FILE *op`.

You should check the return value from `fopen()` to ensure that it worked.  Not doing so and failing to open the file is a sure recipe for trouble.

You need to pass pointers to the integer variables to `fscanf()`.

Note that `fscanf()` could return `0` (or indeed `1`, `2`, or `3`) on malformed data.  These values are all different from `EOF` and all indicate a problem with the input.  The correct test for `fscanf()` is more nearly:

```
int lis = 0;
while(lis < 8 && fscanf(op, "%19[^#] # %19[^#] # %d # %d",
                        name[lis], school[lis], &score[lis], &dis[lis]) == 4) 
    lis++;
fclose(op);
return lis;
```

Note that I've also limited the strings to the size that will fit in the arrays, and returned the number of students that were read.

Finally, for now, I'll observe that `read()` is not a particularly good choice of name.  While it is reserved for the user by standard C, on POSIX systems, `read()` is a system call.  A better name might be `read_students()`.